# Show that the radius of convergence of a sum of series is at least as big as minimum of radii of these series.

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

I am struggling with the following task.

> Suppose $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_nx^n$ has radius of convergence $R$ and $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}b_nx^n$ has radius of convergence $S$.

I want to show that the radius of convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(a_n+b_n)x^n$ is at least as big as the minimum of $T$ and $S$, more precisely - that $T$ (radius of convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(a_n+b_n)x^n$) satisfies:
$$T \geq min(R,S)$$

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Take a point within radius of convergence of both series.  Use finite sums to show the sum of the series converges at that point.  Then use basic facts about radius of convergence of power series.

Answer (score 1):

You have the definition:

> $\sum c_nx^n$ has radius of convergence $T$ if for all $x$ with $|x|<T$ the series $\sum c_nx^n$ converges and for all $x$ with $|x|>T$ the series $\sum c_nx^n$ diverges.

From this definition you can deduce:

> $\sum c_nx^n$ has at least radius of convergence T if for all $x$ with $|x|<T$ the series $\sum c_nx^n$ converges.

This you can use to solve your problem.

**Hint:** If $\sum a_nx^n$ converges and $\sum b_nx^n$ converges, then $\sum (a_n+b_n)x^n$ converges (maybe you try to prove this hint by yourself)

Comment: Thank you! I am able to prove the last thing, but still I cannot really understand how to proceed with the proof.